# disable Ubuntu from thinking that there is a secondary monitor

Tags: sound, hdmi

I know that sound & video are naturally bundled together with HDMI, but I need to figure out a way to disable Ubuntu from thinking that there is a secondary monitor when I plug in the HDMI out of the computer to my digital audio receiver.

Essentially I have a digital receiver that I only want to send audio to via HDMI, but it is making my desktop tricky as it thinks there another monitor, which is creating multiple desktops.

If I disable the monitor in `system prefs`, the audio is no longer passed out the HDMI port.

Is there way to get Ubuntu to only utilize the HMDI to use audio, and not recognize the receiver as a monitor?

thanks

EDIT:

output of `xrandr`:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm panning 1360x768+0+0
   1280x720       60.0 +   50.0     30.0     59.9     30.0     24.0     24.0  
   4096x2160      24.0     24.0  
   3840x2160      30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080      60.0*    50.0     59.9     30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
HDMI2 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 760mm x 450mm panning 1360x768+0+0
   1360x768       60.0*+
   1920x1080      60.0     50.0     59.9     24.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1280x768       59.9  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x576i       50.1  
   720x480        60.0     59.9     59.9  
   720x480i       60.1     60.1  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: im open to any suggestions. Out put of XRANDR is pasted in question now.

Comment: The two screens seem to mirror exactly. Can yoy explain what you mean by: *which is creating multiple desktops*?

Comment: Since Ubuntu thinks that my receiver is a  visual device,  it assigns it a desktop & workspaces that i can not access.  As a workaround I used: xrandr --output HDMI2 --rate 60 --mode 1360x768 --fb 1360x768 --panning 1360x768* --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as HDMI2.   Essentially what this does is it stacks the two desktops on top of each other which gives the environment a single desktop , but this has  led to a whole array of problems which i want to avoid .  I simply wish  to disable  the visual on HDMI  1  but not the audio

Comment: `[1.]`  Would align the two screens (of which one is real) and making it impossible to enter the non-existent screen help? (Can be done) `[2]`  Are the issues related to the *Launcher*, or what are exactly the issues?

Comment: there are plenty of 'workarounds' however I simply wanted to know if there was a way to extrude audio from an HDMI source without the video being interjected. Your first suggestion is my current workaround. The issues are that menus do not position themselves properly on the screen (they will span out of the range of the mouse onto other workspaces), and the system settings drop down menu from the top right corner often spans off the screen as well. Also I quite often have to run the commands above to get back to normal if the amp is ever turned off

Comment: What is '*' doing in the argument for --panning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it does not harm that image is sent to both HDMIs, if you set them in same video mode and position and take care that framebuffer i.e. the current screen size visible in xrandr output has the same resolution. In your xrandr output screen is not large enough to fill HDMI1, which is odd. Run command

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1280x720 --output HDMI2 --mode 1280x720 --same-as HDMI1
```

if you want resolution 1280x720. Framebuffer size should be set automatically to 1280x720, but if it is not, run `xrandr --fb 1280x720`

OR if you have to set mode 1360x768 for HDMI2 and mode 1920x1080 for HDMI1, you could use

```
xrandr --fb 1920x1080 --output HDMI2 --rate 60 --mode 1360x768 --scale-from 1920x1080 --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --same-as HDMI2
```

With lower frame buffer size you could try:

```
xrandr --fb 1360x768 --output HDMI2 --rate 60 --mode 1360x768 --scale 1x1 --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as HDMI2 --scale-from 1360x768
```

Comment: ?? bot screens are already virtually similar. Look at `+0+0`

Comment: @JacobVlijm they have different video mode, look at '*'.

Comment: Yes if you observe the resolutions of the different devices you will see that the lowest common denominator  is 1080p,   however the monitor that I am using is a 720p  monitor  therefore the desired resolution  is 1360x768,   which is something that the audio receiver can not output .

Comment: @KalamalkaKid If you have 720p monitor, why not use  1280x720 resolution? That resolution is listed for both outputs.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid anyway, I added a solution for the case in which you use different modes for different outputs (but with same aspect ratio).

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I think it would be more optimal, if you could use the same or lower resolution for HDMI1 than for HDMI2, and use framebuffer size matching the resolution of HDMI2.

Comment: the 720p resolution looks grainy., The 1360x768 looks best.  In any case, what I was REALLY looking for was not a workaround (as I already have one), but more so looking to see if there is anyway to disable the secondary monitor form showing up without killing the sound. I think Im probably going to just have to buy another television set that will support the modes that the receiver sends out (1080p).

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Apparently it is 768p monitor then; the + sign in xrandr output reveals it. I think it is odd that higher resolution modes are even listed for the output.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I wonder, if my workaround works better as for menus than the one you tell in the 3rd comment to you question?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I added still one more workaround with no scaling on the output you actually use for displaying image.

Comment: Why it is so important to you to have no image sent to the receiver? Besides, it seems to be [impossible](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/162597) to send solely audio. If I understood right, you have no TV connected to the receiver and even if there was, you don't have to keep it on, if it disturbs  you.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Actually, I think my solution is not a workaround, as it shouldn't make your desktop tricky or create multiple desktops, which was your concern.

Comment: i couldnt stand dealing with the monitor always changing resolutions, and stretching out so i went out and bought a TV. While I do not consider this totally solved, , I appreciate your help. I hope in the future people can use this information to their advantage. I gave you the bounty

Comment: one last question now my xrandr is: Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 890mm x 500mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     30.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 - why is it only showing two available resolutions now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35948/discussion-between-jarno-and-kalamalka-kid).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting the HDMI monitor off by using command `xrandr --output HDMIDEVICE --off` works better than using `system prefs`. Replace word HDMIDEVICE by the name of the HDMI output. You can probably get the name by command `xrandr | grep -o '^HDMI[^ ]*` in terminal.

Select the right audio output port and configuration profile in Output Devices tab and Configuration tab in `pavucontrol`.

Comment: As stated in the question (disabling the other output), xrandr --output HDMIDEVICE --off disables the audio.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Oh, I thought doing it in `system prefs`would do it somehow differently.  (I am using Xubuntu where there is `xfce4-display-settings` for monitor control.)

Comment: @KalamalkaKid couldn't you then enable audio using `pavucontrol`?

Comment: Since the audio and  the video signal are recognized  together ,  disabling HDMI1 in the display settings  removes  the device from the available audio  outputs.

Comment: I have the same question. I have a NVidia card and am running the video thru the DP port and audio thru the HDMI port. Ubuntu 22 sees both ports as 2 monitors, which is causing windowing problems. There seems to be no means to cause NVidia or Ubuntu to cut the video and allow only the audio to pass. Here we are 6 years later and still no resolution to this issue.